# C++, static и неявное обнуление полей составного объекта

Tags: c++, static, singleton

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Singleton
{
    public:

    static const Singleton& instance()
    {
        const static Singleton singleton;
        return singleton;
    }

    private:

    Singleton()
    {}

    uint64_t array_a[10];
    std::array<uint64_t, 10> array_b;
};
```

Меня интересует следующий вопрос.

Поскольку `singleton` является статическим, для него можно ожидать инициализации нулями. По этой причине в конструкторе можно не делать обнуление содержимого `array_a` и `array_b`, оно и так будет обнулено, еще до вызова конструктора.

Действительно ли это так?

Comment: Вполне возможно, что я неправ, но imho - для него можно ожидать инициализацию конструктором по умолчанию, и все...

Comment: В обоих случаях память нам выделят на стеке, но что нам гарантирует инициализацию памяти?

Comment: @JK_Action, `static` гарантирует выделение памяти в статической области, не на стеке.

Answer (score 1):

Независимо от способа размещения массива, в обоих слчаях для элементов массива быдет вызвам default initialization. Т.е. значение элементов будет неопределено.

Если хотите инициализировать массивы определенными значениями, инициализируйте их в конструкторе:

```
Singleton()
  : array_a({0}), array_b({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
{}
```

или (начиная с С++11) в точке декларации переменной:

```
uint64_t array_a[10]={0};
std::array<uint64_t, 10> array_b={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

В любом зи этих подходов, гарантий что память под эти маасвы будет инициализирован на стадии инициализации статических объектов - нет. Естественный способ получить такие гарантии - объявить статическим сам массв. (Он все равно присуствует в единственном экземпляре, поскольку синглетон.)

```
static uint64_t array_a[10]={0};
```

Если нужно инициализировать константу веремени компиляции, то есть два варианта: (1) иницаилизировать готовым набором значений (воспользоваться препроцессором, или просто подсчитать значения в отлдельной программе); (2) написать constexpr функцию, которая вернет std::array. Например:

```
static constexpr uint64_t calc_table_item(size_t i) // вычисление элемента
{
    return i==0 ? 0 : ( calc_table_item(i-1)*2+1 );
}

template< size_t ... ii >
static constexpr std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(ii)> fill_table( std::index_sequence<ii...> )
{
    return { calc_table_item(ii)... };
}

static constexpr auto array_b=fill_table( std::make_index_sequence<256>{} );
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы ошибаетесь. Поскольку `singleton` размещается в статической области памяти, все его содержимое зануляется неявно.

Comment: @MGNeo, Хотя физически массвы будут размещены в  статической памяти, исключение о статической инициализации POD объектов до вызова конструкторов на него нераспространяется, поскольку он является частью объекта, который обладает конструктором. Компилятор имеет возможность перенести часть инициализации (фактически часть конструтора), на этап инициализации статических объектов, но не обязан это делать.

Comment: статическая память сразу после старта программы как минимум занулена. Поэтому, содержимое объекта, расположенного в статической памяти, как минимум занулено, еще до вызова конструктора.

Comment: @MGNeo нет. Конкретное значение зависит от реализации. Кроме того при вызове конструктора он все равно имеет право (обязан, если у конструкторе указаны нули) заполнить эту память новыми значениями.

Comment: В любом случае явная инициализация будет нагляднее, что снижает риск ошибки при переезде кода на другую платформу, например.